# Decrypt database before Hibernate creates new one in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, derby

I have Spring application which use Derby embedded database and Hibernate as ORM. In order to protect it, I have developed encryption mechanism, which pack entire database into one file and encrypt it.

After application start there should be dialog, where user can type password and start decryption of database, but after start Spring launch Hibernate which creates new database and do not wait for decryption of old one. Is there any way how to wait for decryption and then resume application initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lazy-init="true"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)j to delay the initialization of a bean until it gets accessed first. Also you might want to use this setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

to disable hibernate recreating the database schema from scratch.